# asp.net config deny users="?" doesn't work for ALL files

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have a website and under it an application.

Following the tut here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648341.aspx I created a secure folder inside the application.

Then web.config was added in the folder of the application but still I can access secure folder what did I do wrong ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    </system.web>
  <!-- The secure folder is for authenticated and SSL access only. -->
  <location path="Secure" >
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>  
</configuration>
```

Update: finally I had an index.html and when I replaced by Default.aspx it did work.

Then how to protect ANY file without adding extension one by one :(

Comment: what are you still able to access? images, aspx pages, txt files? authorization only prevents access to specific types of files.

Answer (score 2):

The authentication tag might be missing. This code works for me:

```
<system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms cookieless="AutoDetect" protection="All" slidingExpiration="true" loginUrl="~/login.aspx"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
<location path="styles">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="images">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="scripts">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: why you are using impersonation?

Comment: @Nudier: I found this code in an old project of mine. This line may be  unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the empty first system.web and you don't need to wrap the second one in a location tag.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only thing you're missing is this :

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
</system.webServer>

<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Default.aspx">
        </forms>
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

This is what I have and it works :

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Default.aspx">
        </forms>
    </authentication>
</system.web>
<location path="secure">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
   <configuration>
    <system.web>
   ...
   <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name="MyAppCookie" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" path="/" />
 </authentication>
  </system.web>
  ...
     //deny the access to annonymous users in the Secure directory
    <location path="Secure" >
      <system.web>
    <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
   </authorization>
    </system.web>
   </location>  
</configuration>
```